# How do I add an `<i>` to the text of a submit_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to duplicate this, in a submit tag:

```
<%= link_to "<i class='icon-shopping-cart icon-large'></i> Checkout (#{number_to_currency(@item.price, precision: 0)})".html_safe, @item.link.url, class: "btn btn-success btn-large"%>
```

So I tried this:

```
<%= submit_tag "<i class='icon-shopping-cart icon-large'></i> Checkout (#{number_to_currency(@item.price, precision: 0)})".html_safe, :id => "submit", class: "btn btn-success btn-large" %>
```

But that didn't work. It just gave me a huge ass button with some HTML in the text of the submit.

How do I escape the HTML?

**Edit 1**

Here is the HTML generated by the `submit_tag`:

```
<input class="btn btn-success btn-large" id="submit" name="commit" type="submit" value="&lt;i class='icon-shopping-cart icon-large'&gt;&lt;/i&gt; Checkout ($7)">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `button_tag`, I haven't test it, but it accepts a block:

```
button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn btn-success btn-large") do
  "<i class='icon-shopping-cart icon-large'></i> Checkout (#{number_to_currency(@item.price, precision: 0)})".html_safe
end
```

Search "button_tag" in http://api.rubyonrails.org/

Hope this helps!

Comment: That does work if you add `.html_safe` at the end of the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Submit buttons cannot contain any embedded html, thus your best bet is something like:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-large" id="submit">
  <i class='icon-shopping-cart icon-large'></i> Checkout <%= number_to_currency(@item.price, precision: 0) %>
</button>
```

Comment: I can't use a `<button>` tag - even though I like this solution. I have edited the question to include the HTML generated by the `submit_tag`. Any ideas on how to hard code that?

Comment: Any reason why you can't use the button tag? I just tested with bootstrap and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: You are right @luis-ramalho - it does work. I prefer the `button_tag` version though.